# ListView Item Selected State not working

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

So I have a ListView and I want to change the color of each items background and text. This ListView is inside a ListFragment. My code inflates the layout in the `onCreateView` and inflates the layout of each item in the `newView`.

The `android:state_pressed="true"` is working fine, whenever I press in one item the background changes to that color. But when selecting an item neither the bg color or text color changes, even though I've defined an item with `android:state_selected="true"` in the selector.

Edit: I'm using SDK level 11 (Android 3.0) and a Motorola Xoom.

The list fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The list item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_selector">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/form_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/form_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The background selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_selected" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/list_bg" />
</selector>
```

The text selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/list_text_blue" />
</selector>
```

Comment: @Snicolas I don't think that question is related to this one, I'm not even using semitransparent colors

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The answer is to use the `android:state_activated="true"` state, instead of the "selected" state. More on this here: [ListFragment Item Selected Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331587/listfragment-item-selected-background)

Comment: can you check my question here please, i think you can answer it :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644517/xml-background-dont-change-when-i-use-tablet
Tahnks

Comment: Does not work for me. Can you post up an example XML drawable for the states?

Comment: Doesn't work with API v10 and bellow. See my post with better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution with support of all API levels is to implement Checkable feature for list item `View` which means that the top view of your list item layout has to implement `Checkable` interface (in my case it was TextView, but the same can be applied on `ViewGroup` classes like `LinearLayout`). When you click on a list item, the `ListView` call `setChecked` method and there we change the state of View to use `android:state_checked="true"` selector. Together with list view `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` it will select only one item.

The trick is to override `onCreateDrawableState` method and set the checked state here for drawables. See example of `SelectableTextView` bellow. After the `setChecked` is called, the checked state is stored and called `refreshDrawableState`.

Example of `SelectableTextView`:

```
package com.example.widget.SelectableTextView;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SelectableTextView extends TextView implements Checkable {
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
                    android.R.attr.state_checked
    };

    private boolean mChecked;

    public SelectableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SelectableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SelectableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SelectableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setSelected(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

Example of `selectable_list_item.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.widget.SelectableTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:textColor="@color/list_item_selector_foreground"
          android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_background"
          tools:text="Item 1"/>
```

Example of `list_item_selector_foreground.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- checked -->
    <item android:color="@color/list_item_text_active" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:color="@color/list_item_text"/>
</selector>
```

Example of `list_item_selector_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_item_background_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_item_background_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_item_background_active" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/list_item_background"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This worked fore me.. simple and correct approach

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to set `clickable="true"` for the layout. This solved my problem.

List item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_selector"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNewsPreviewTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/news_preview_title_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Background selector:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
                <gradient android:startColor="@color/white" android:endColor="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/holo_gray_darker" />
                <gradient android:startColor="@color/holo_gray_bright" android:endColor="@color/holo_gray_bright" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew S: Along with using activated state in selector , activated state must be set to false for default case as shown in below selector code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_activated="false"
        android:color="@color/dark_text_blue"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/red"/>
  <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:color="@color/red"/>
</selector>
```